# Avoid or improve angular service calls that tend to be dependent on the result of previous call

Tags: angular

I have a simple form where a user enters a code and clicks on the search button:

1. Search logic

   ```
   Search(code: string) {

   this.Backend.getMetaData(code)
       .then(resp => { // get information for the input code
           this.metaData = resp; // store response in the `metaData` var

             // if this particular key exists in the response from backend
           if ('productionProcessTemplate' in this.metaData) { 
               // this.getBPInfo(resp['productionProcessTemplate']);
               this.getAnalysis(code);
           }
            // if this particular key exists in the response from backend
           if ('eventUrl' in resp) {
               this.getTableInfo(resp['eventUrl'], code);
           }
       })
       .catch(error => {
           this.error_detc = true;
       });
   }
   ```

As the calls to `getAnalysis(code)` and `getTableInfo(..)` are functions which also call other services similar to `Search(code)`

**`getAnalysis(code)`**

```
getAnalysis(code) {
    this.Backend.getAnalysisInfo(code)
        .subscribe((res) => {
            this.error_detc = false;
            this.bpInfo = res;
        }, (err) => {
            this.error_detc = true;
        });
}
```

**`getTableInfo(resp['eventUrl'], code)`**

```
getTableInfo(url, code) {
    this.Backend.getTrackingInfo(url, code)
        .subscribe((resp_track) => {
            this.error_detc = false;
            this.trackingInfo = resp_track.map(el => {
                let _out = {
                    'eventTime': moment(el.eventTime.$date).utcOffset(el.eventTimeZoneOffset).toString(),
                    'bizStep': el.bizStep.split(':').pop(),
                    'action': el.action,
                    'readPoint': el.readPoint.id.split(':').pop(),
                    'bizLocation': ''
                };
                if ('bizLocation' in el) {
                    _out['bizLocation'] = el.bizLocation.id.split(':').pop();
                    return _out;
                }
                return _out;
            });
        }, (err) => {
            this.error_detc = true;
        });
}
```

the calls to such services seem like a Waterfall where Information for the next step is obtained on only if:

1. Data is available from the first service call
2. if there are particular keys in the response of the first call

Is there a better practice for such a scenario in Angular? There could be a scenario that if First endpoint goes down the complete Component would stop functioning.

Comment: Instead of subscribing directly to the async call in `getAnalysis` and `getTableInfo`, let them cascade the observables and use the appropriate [rxjs operators](https://www.learnrxjs.io/) to handle your logic in the `search` function